# Does toggleclass work with js generated html?

Tags: javascript

I'm generating html content using an ajax data. Here is my code:

```
$('.expand').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('open')});


function Get_id(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "here is my url with api_key",
    datatype: "json",
    method: "GET", // Что бы воспользоваться POST методом, меняем данную строку на POST   
    success: displayJson
  });
}
Get_id();


function displayJson(jsonData){
    let result='';
    console.log(jsonData['applications']);
     for (let i in jsonData["applications"]) {
     let goods ='<ul class=goods-container>'
     for(let j in jsonData["applications"][i]["goods"]){
        goods +='<li class="good">'+jsonData["applications"][i]["goods"][j].name+'</li>';
     }
      let endtime = '';
      let o_num = '';
      endtime += '<p>'+jsonData["applications"][i]["planDeliveryPeriod"].endDate.slice(11, 16)+'</p>';

      goods += '</ul>';

      result += '<div class=order-container><p>'+jsonData["applications"][i]["customId"]+'</p>'+endtime+'<div class="expand"></div></div>';

      $(".output").html(result);
    }
    setTimeout(Get_id, 30000);
}
```

So toggleclass doesn`t work here with , but if i have this html structure without js, it does. So is my problem in generating the html in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change first line like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.expand', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open')}
});
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But if it is not hard for you, could u explain what happened?

Comment: thats because div with `expand` class is dynamic html and the event listener :$('.expand').click(callbackFunction()) only works with pre-generated html.
if you want event on html that are rendered after load of page you have to use above syntax.(I suggest you to use always)

Comment: You can also check doc for more details : https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

In your code the first line you wrote will search for elements matching `.expand` and add event-listeners to them. But since the element doesn't yet exist when the statement is run, it won't add any listeners.

You either have to run the statement after the element gets added or add the event listener to the body and check if the target matched `.expand`.

Here is an example:

```js
$(".test").on("click", printMethod.bind("Direct Listener 1"));
$("body").on("click", ".test", printMethod.bind("Body Listener"));

var newButton = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
newButton.className = "test", newButton.textContent = "2";

$(".test").on("click", printMethod.bind("Direct Listener 2"));

function printMethod() {
  console.log(String(this));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="test">1</button>
```